# websocket-rails how to close socket connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I'm switching over from `ActionController:Live` to `websocket-rails`, and I was just wondering how to close the connection on the server side once the user closes the browser window?

With ActionController:Live I used to have:

```
def stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    @redis_sub = RedisStream.new_redis_client



    # Subscribing to user's stream by session token
    @redis_sub.subscribe([ token ]) do |on|
        on.message do |channel, msg|
            ## Did stuff
            response.stream.write(msg)
        end
    end

 rescue IOError
    "\n\nIOError in controller"
 rescue ClientDisconnected
    puts "\n\nClient has disconnected\n\n"
 ensure
    @redis_sub.quit
    response.stream.close
 end
```

And this worked fine, now I'm trying to do the same thing as this but using websockets, and I was wondering how to close the connection and quit out of my redis subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connection.close!` from within the websocket controller.

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/219

Comment: any idea how to do it outside of the websocket controller?

Answer (score 0):

To deepen a little in @TheNastyOne answer, you can close socket a connection from `dispatcher` on client side like this:

```
// Open connection.
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket'); 

// Close connection.
dispatcher.disconnect();
```

[Here](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/356) lives the issue that describe both methods.